# Can't download PDF (FPDF) from PHP function

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am working on a PHP MVC application right now and I am having some troubles with FPDF. The code is pretty simple, but it won't download the PDF file (Also tried to open it and it doesn't work). I think I am missing something or maybe I need to disable something from the fpdf instance, but I can't reach the problem to solve it. Here's the code:

```
public function downloadPDF(){

require('../FPDF/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();

$numero = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,8,2003);
date_default_timezone_set("Atlantic/Canary");
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","",14);
$pdf->AddPage();
$mifecha = gmmktime(0,0,0,2,1,2013);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,strtoupper(strftime("%B",$mifecha)),1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","",10);
$pdf->Cell(60,10,"By Ricky",0,1,"C");

$pdf->Output($pdf,"D");

}
```

Just in case: the idea is that using this function will automatically download the PDF file. For example, when clicking a "Download PDF" button in my menu.

Comment: Isn't this more related to your MVC application? How do you send the response for other content types to the client? The call of Output() with "D" in the snd argument send PDF specific headers and the PDF bytes. You must not send any other byte before or after the Output() call. If you need to send the headers and content your own, use "S" and forward the return value to your application response.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost a problem of header() somewhere into your MVC:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");
```

if you set correctly those, you should be alright.

Remember that header() must be called before any input or it won't work

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was such an obvious mistake I didn't notice. I was using this:

```
$pdf->Output($pdf,"D");
```

FPDF's Output function receives two string parameters (name, output type). Instead of giving this function a name string, I was giving it the $pdf object instead. It worked perfectly when I fixed it, it ended up like this:

```
$pdf->Output("PDF name","I");
```

By the way, thanks for your support.